# “Cease fire” vs. “Cease firing”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, difference

The man ordered his men to cease **fire**/ **firing**.

It seems to me 
If I say: to cease fire would means: they may not be firing at the time of order.

But cease firing, it seems they were firing, and their leader told them to stop firing immediately?

Am I right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

No, actually *"Cease fire!"* and *"Cease firing!"* mean the same thing, and are used in the same way.  While "cease firing" might seem to make more sense, "cease fire" is a common idiomatic expression.  Both require that the men being commanded are currently firing.

Side note:  A "ceasefire" (compound noun) is a temporary pause in hostilities, not to be confused with the order to "cease fire".

Answer (score 1):

Both **fire** and **firing** are non-finite.

**Fire** has the aspect of the action *per se*

**Firing** has the aspect of continuous or repeated action.

Compare:

Stop that!

Stop doing that!

Comment: Note though that "cease walking" would be grammatical, but uncommon but "cease walk" is not grammatical.

Comment: Agreed, but under certain non-quotidien circumstances, even **cease walk** could very well be grammatical. Let's say you're Ground Control Leader at NASA, giving orders regarding a planetary "walker" explorer vehicle of some kind as it moves about the surface of Mars.  You could bark "Cease walk!" when the vehicle got too close to a crater-edge, say.

Comment: Maybe, but that seems a stretch. The point I would emphasize is that "cease fire" is a fixed-expression, or at least can be treated as one and thus may not hold up to piece-by-piece grammatical analysis

Comment: @eques 12: Your comment would be better appended to Andrew's answer if you're interested in possible idiomatic combinations with **cease**.  In the context of *command brevity*, **cease** can be productive, e.g. **cease dive!** by a submarine captain. But my answer sought to address OP's question about **fire** vs **firing** and his mistaken impression that "they may not be firing at the time of order" with respect to the command "cease fire".

Comment: Andrew's answer points out the idiomatic nature; yours contrasts fire from firing but inaccurately and without completely distinguishing the two.

Comment: I do distinguish the two.  What specifically is inaccurate? Your comment about **walk** clarified nothing in terms of any inaccuracy.

Comment: "has the aspect of the action" vs "continuous or repeated". The present participle always means in progress. What is "aspect of the action" supposed to mean? I wouldn't ordinarily associate "repeated" to the present participle

Comment: @eques  If you're going to quote, quote accurately. "has the aspect of the action *per se*".

Comment: And that changes it how apart from softening? "aspect of the action" is still a vague phrasing at best

Comment: @eques:   Why not take a crack yourself at explaining the difference between **fire** and **firing**.  Not just labeling them, but explaining the difference between the two non-finite forms.

Comment: I don't need to take a crack at it; there are already sufficient good answers

Comment: You wrote "The present participle always means in progress." Consider: *How is he getting to work? -- He is taking the train.*   Do you regard **taking** there as referring to an action "in progress"?

Comment: The issue with yours was more about "repeated". The full details of when present participles are used and how telicity and aspects are understood is beyond the scope of this comment thread

Answer (score 1):

"Ceasefire" is most commonly used as a noun meaning a suspension of hostilities between two parties in an armed conflict. It's also used metaphorically to mean a reduction in hostility between two parties in any kind of conflict.

Grammatically, "cease fire" or "cease firing" would also be understood as commands, but *cease* is a very formal word and not one you'd expect to be used in an emotional moment (like when shooting at people and being shot at).

"Hold your fire" is a more common idiomatic way for a military officer to command soldiers to stop shooting, at least in TV and movies (even if the literal meaning is to wait to begin shooting). (Although I am not a veteran and I don't know if there's a specific wording called for by military regulations in the US or any other country)

Comment: Sombody with more Ngram-foo might be able to search for "cease fire" (the command) without also getting hits for "ceasefire" (the noun).